# loadXML can't parse all Umlauts html entities... PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have text in xml file, "BOXXenb&amp:ouml:den", so it will only convert to "BOXXenb&ouml:den"

```
$a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <text id="349|Produkt - caption (349)|hellölk">BOXXenb&amp;ouml;den.</text>
';
$oXml        = new DomDocument();
    $oXml->loadXML($a);
file_put_contents('D:/oXml.log',print_r($oXml,1),8);
print_r($oXml);
```

So in my oXml.log file i can see that "BOXXenb&ouml:den." and by print_r($oXml); on browser by i see the "BOXXenböden."
Yes i know that while displaying on browser, it converts all html entities, but my problem i am storing these values in database, so "BOXXenb&ouml:den." this value get stored, so can you tell me how to handle this case?
Thanks.

Here above too, above in my first line &amp:ouml: get converted to &ouml:, it's because of browser.
**Note - i am purposely posting : instead of ; to prevent from convert by browser.**

Comment: *"on browser, it converts all html entities, but my problem i am storing these values in database, so "BOXXenböden." this value get stored"* ... which value - the one with the actual **ö** character or the HTML encoded version?

Comment: yes right, the one with [&ouml;] one

Comment: You should probably *not* be storing the HTML encoded versions in the database but yeah... wysiwyg plugins... can you not just chuck `$a` at `html_entity_decode()` before passing it into your `DomDocument` ? Or are there likely to be `<` or `>` characters in it?